# Excel vba code to copy names found in multiple worksheets and count how many times they appear

Tags: vba

I need some help writing some VBA code.

Basically I have one spreadsheet with 4 worksheets (CLIENT1, CLIENT2, CLIENT3, CLIENT4)

Each worksheet contains a column called CONTACT.
This CONTACT column contains a person name
The CONTACT column can be in a different position in each worksheet ie the CONTACT column in CLIENT1 is in Column D whereas it appears in column E in CLIENT2

I would like some help writing some code that will create a new Worksheet called SUMMARY.

The SUMMARY worksheet would contain in Column A a list of all the names found in the CONTACT column and in Column B it would count the number of times that persons name was found.

So the SUMMARY worksheet would end up looking something like this.

```
        A           B
1   John Smith      4
2   Brad Black      2
3   Gary Soth       1
4   Bob Brown       6
5   Sam Drow        2
```

Hope this makes sense and thanks for your help

Andy

Comment: Love to help you but I'm not going to write all of it. Start by showing what you've produced so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that in Excel you can use the Remove Duplicates function to remove all unwanted names. I can then use the count function across all 4 worksheets to get the required information.

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Note : I am just playing with Excel and not using VBA but think you can achieve it without using VBA also.

You can use `COUNTIF` and solve your problem.

I will show you step by step.  I cant attach excel here so adding images. If you wish to have excel which i prepared then just give me your email, I will send it.

This is summary which I got by using the formula (you can see that highlighted :

[image: Summary]

Client Name column can get value from the sheet where you can combine all your unique client names and use that as base.

[image: Summary Name column]

Check Client1, 2, 3 & 4 sheets.

[image: Client1]

[image: Client2]

[image: Cilent3]

[image: Client4]

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks Nilesh. Appreciate your help. The only problem with your solution is producing the MASTER worksheet with a list of all the Names. CLIENT1 contains 9000 names, CLIENT2 contains 6000 names, CLIENT 3 contain 14000 names and CLIENT4 contains 600 names. I can copy these names from each of the CLIENT worksheets but then I get duplicates. I could sort the MASTER worksheet and then delete any duplicates but as you can appreciate this would be very time consuming. I will keep looking for a way of extracting each unique name from each of the worksheets.  Thanks for your time. Andy